# SQL concatenate rows into one field (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2, concatenation

I need to extract some data from my DB2 database. I have keywords in one table and each keyword is a separate row. In the extract I want to have all keywords for all IDs in one string separated by a comma.

So, to explain:
I have such data

```
ID         | keyword 
===========================
prd1       | test
---------------------------
prd2       | keywords
---------------------------
prd1       | flower
---------------------------
prd4       | picture
---------------------------
prd7       | 234567
---------------------------
prd9       | reored
---------------------------
prd4       | finland
---------------------------
prd0       | 983y23
---------------------------
prd4       | code
---------------------------
prd9       | tratata
```

And here is a sample of what I want to achieve:

```
ID         | keyword concatenated
===========================
prd1       | test, flower
---------------------------
prd2       | keywords
---------------------------
prd4       | picture, finland, code
---------------------------
prd7       | 234567
---------------------------
prd9       | reored, tratata
---------------------------
prd0       | 983y23
---------------------------
```

I tried with `concat`:

```
SELECT concat(keyword) FROM table.keywordTbl
```

I tried with some DB2 specific commands:

```
SELECT IDs, Sys_Connect_By_Path(varchar(keyword), ', ') AS "keyword concatenated" FROM table.keywordTbl START WITH ID='prd1' CONNECT BY ID=keyword
```

`PIVOT` is not right for this, but I have checked it too.
`GROUP_CONCAT` is not working either.

Of course, none of these work...

Do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to modify query accordingly to the below script

```
 SELECT 
    ID, 
    SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(CONCAT( ', ',keyword))) as VARCHAR(1024)), 3) AS "keyword concatenated"
    FROM table.keywordTbl 
    GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 33):

You can also use `LISTAGG()` function, if you have `DB2 v9.7+`. The first parameter is the column, the second is separator.

```
SELECT 
  ID
, LISTAGG(keyword, ',') AS "keyword concatenated"
    FROM table.keywordTbl 
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This works amazingly! Adding to this if one wants to concatenate removing duplicates one can pass in Distinct to ListAgg. 

   ,LISTAGG(Distinct keyword, ',') as "keyword concatenated"