# Concatenate the contents of two rows into one column (SQL DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

as it says in the title, I need to return two records but in the same column, for example (I clarify that the following code does not work, it is only to understand my case):

```
SELECT (NAMESS + "|" + LASTNAMESS), AGE
FROM PERSON
```

When doing the query, it would have to return something like Johnny|Depp in the first column and 45 in the second

Comment: Luckily, [there is documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/el/db2-for-zos/12?topic=expressions-concatenation-strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL concatenate rows into one field (DB2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805101/sql-concatenate-rows-into-one-field-db2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods to concat the fields in DB2.

1. CONCAT function -

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAMESS, LASTNAMESS), AGE
FROM PERSON;
```

2. Concat Operator i.e. '||' -

```
SELECT NAMESS || LASTNAMESS, AGE
FROM PERSON;
```